# Selfsigned SSL multidomain certificates

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, subdomain

My main goal is to create a self-signed certificate for two domains:

- mydomain.com
- www.mydomain.com

I've already followed some tutorials using the req_v3 and this is a sample of generated csr file:

```
    Attributes:
        challengePassword        :unable to print attribute
    Requested Extensions:
        X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
            CA:FALSE
        X509v3 Key Usage: 
            Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, Key Encipherment
        X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
            DNS:mydomain.com, DNS:www.mydomain.com
Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
     7a:5f:85:9f:8f:00:01:8a:c4:a4:bf:8a:fe:a9:70:f2:94:db:
     e2:e7:03:68:33:29:50:10:9c:54:36:e1:24:52:b5:c3:ae:1d:
```

When I try to access to mydomain.com the only warning browser shows me is that is not a trusted certificate, of course because is self-signed, I'm ok with that.

The problem is when I try to access to www.mydomain.com, apart of not trusted certificate warning, it also shows me that server certificate does not include an id which matches the server name.

Here is a my vhost configuration file:
http://codeshare.io/VtBOQ

Comment: When accepting the exception in the browser, have you actually checked that this is indeed the certificate you're getting, not something else from a previous configuration attempt?

Comment: yes, I always check that changes are loaded... I'm still looking for, maybe my bad is I'm using v3_req and it seems that for self-signed I need to work with v3_ca

Comment: Sorry, I don't just mean whether the changes are loaded, I mean if you click on the address bar icon (may vary depending on the browser you use), and look at the certificate details, is it what you expect?

Comment: Yes, I check the cert in the bar browser too, and in both cases is what I expect

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using req_v3 steps, which are usually followed to generate a csr file which is then used for a trusted sign request, we have to use req_ca for self-signed certificates as you can see on this little tutorial:

http://fbcs.co.uk/self-signed-multiple-domain-ssl-certificates/